# Should I scrape bubbled skim coat off to repair my ceiling?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, painting

We have a drywall ceiling with a couple butt joint seams that were visible.  Had a guy come in and I think (a few years ago) used Durabond to feather them out.

Last week I thought I would tackle it all and give it a skimcoat (joint compound, rolled on and smoothed out) which looked great.  I let it set for a few days and sanded any imperfections.  I primed it. And then used Valspar ceiling paint (the stuff that goes on pink, turns white).

The areas where the Durabond was used bubbled or actually weakened. The skimmed joint compound was not sticking to the Durabond--I could easily pull the skim off those areas.  I think I will need to scrape out the sections that come off easily and redo.  But should I prime the Durabond sections and then skim over it?  I am hoping the entire ceiling does not come off either, going to test it later.

Comment: That's very odd. Joint compounds should not react that way. They're both quite porous and should bond well. What joint compound did you use? Did you water it down?

Comment: I did water it down a little to skim it a bit.  It was a 5 gal bucket of regular joint compound.

Comment: Setting type compounds need the proper water mixture to work. Anytime I need a thin mix I use standard mud it won’t be affected but durabond that I use is 20 minute setting compound. Prior to doing any mud work I will usually go over the area with a sponge mop to pull any dust off the surface.

Comment: So after I scrape/sand off the loose bits, I guess wipe down, use a primer and then skim the sections again?

Comment: I just went and tried scraping around one of the areas and pretty well stuck on.  I wonder if I should have let all the layers (joint, primer, paint) cure for longer periods

Comment: "*joint compound, **rolled on** and smoothed out*"  Are you saying you rolled on mud with a roller? Skim coats are skimmed on with a drywall knife or a float. ??  Primer goes on after the skim coat. More details please.

Comment: I used a roller to apply and then used a drywall knife to smooth it out.  I saw some videos online of guys doing entire rooms with a roller and then smoothing out.

Comment: That is new for me, it seems the roller would introduce anomalies.

Comment: Same, but I saw instructions (https://drywall101.com/articles/taping/rollskim.php#:~:text=Using%20a%20paint%20roller%20with,four%20feet%20by%20eight%20feet.) and  a video on YT and was amazed. PRetty crazy.

Comment: SO I checked the ceiling, when the joint was flaking out, took a scraper and tried flaking off more and its stuck on the ceiling.  Wonder if I had a curing issue.